# Information retrieval performance measures for unknown test collection?

Tags: measurement, information-retrieval

I am evaluating a web search relevance feedback algorithm. The algorithm uses Bing API as source for its result sets. To evaluate the algorithm I will be conducting a user study.

In the end I will have binary judgements, whether the documents are a good answer to the query. Since the web as a test collection is big, I can't calculate recall, because I don't know the amount relavant documents, which are not found.

The only measure I can think of is precision, because it uses only the result set and the judgements.

Question: **Are there other performance measures (besides precision), which would work on documents returned by a web search?**